# Using shared preferences (Android)

Tags: android, preferences

I am trying to save some data in shared preferences on Android and as the following page says (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref), I should write some code like the code shown bellow inside onCreate() method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_tablet);

    //Restore preferences
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
    setSilent(silent);
}
```

The problem is that the last line:

```
 setSilent(silent);
```

gives an error shown as:

> The method setSilent(boolean) is undefined for the type MainActivity

What should I do to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: where is setSilent() defined? you need a method declaration like public void setSilent(boolean silent){}

Comment: It looks like setSilent() is not defined, you should define it somewhere in MainActivity

Comment: The link which you provide,they just passing the shared preference return value as a parameter into setSilent which was defined somewhere else, just remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save a value in using sharedpreferences:

```
SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("Test",0);
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("VALUE", value);
editor.commit();
```

And get it like that:

```
SharedPreferences prfs = getSharedPreferences("Test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String v= prfs.getString("VALUE", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line:

```
setSilent(silent);
```

The value you need has already been stored in the variable `silent`. The above line was presumably included to demonstrate what you can do with the variable

Answer (score 0):

To get stored value using SharedPreference

```
private String getOnPreference() {
    String prefName = null;
    try {

        SharedPreferences myPrefs2 = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",
                MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefName = myPrefs2.getString("key",value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Get error in shared preference", e);
    }
    return prefName;
}
```

To set value using Shared preference

```
private void setOnPreference(String value) {
                try {
                    SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",
                            MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
                    prefsEditor.putString("key", value);
                    prefsEditor.commit();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.error("Set error in shared preference", e);
                }
            }
```

Simply use the above functions to get and set any data using shared preference